# Obtaining a list of date to control file import

Tags: oracle

I have a need to pull in via FTP only files from dates I haven't pulled data.  The data pulls happen nightly, but occasionally there is an issue and a night gets skipped, and it will be picked up the following night.
I located a query on StackOverflow which addressed *most* of my problem.  However, I'm left with an uncomfortable solution and a lingering question.

I have a table with data from each file downloaded. The crux of the data I'm using for this example is EXTRACT_DATE. The file format is filename_20160809.csv, as an example.  Uses the 4-digit year, 2-digit month and 2-digit day to make unique. The FTP location has thousands of files, and I only want to grab the new, based on this date.

First, I get the latest EXTRACT_DATE from my table as such

```
SELECT MAX(EXTRACT_DATE) INTO checkDate FROM FILE_DETAILS;
```

I had attempted to do this in a single query, but couldn't work it, and finally attempted to create a variable, checkDate, and use this variable in a subsequent query to obtain my list. However, having two queries in a single script is not allowed, or I haven't found a way to do it.  So my primary issue is to return the value of the latest date.  Then call a new query or procedure with the value incorporated in to obtain my list, with this query

```
SELECT TO_DATE(checkDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') + rownum AS EXTRACT_DATES
FROM ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE TO_DATE(checkDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')  + rownum <= TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YY');
```

This solution is messy and uncomfortable, I would prefer a single query to get back my results, rather then 2 scripts or a script and a procedure.

The lingering question, the result from the query returns dates in the mm/dd/yyyy format; 8/9/2016.  I adjusted the TO_DATE to match.
Initially, it was set to return as YYYY-MM-DD; 2016-08-09.
However, it wouldn't return in this format.  It would only come back as 8/9/2016, regardless of the TO_DATE formatting used. I don't understand why the date is coming back in this format.

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2-AUG-2016', 'DD-MON-RR') + rownum AS EXTRACT_DATES
FROM ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE TO_DATE('2-AUG-2016', 'DD-MON-RR')  + rownum <= TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YY');
```

EXTRACT_DATES
8/3/2016
8/4/2016
8/5/2016
8/6/2016
8/7/2016
8/8/2016
8/9/2016

NLS_DATE_FORMAT is set to DD-MON-RR, with American as NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE.

Comment: You are executing the query in sqlplus ?

Comment: yes, sqlplus in the python script, and TOAD for ad-hoc test scripts.

Comment: Did you try to use to_char('value','format_mask') after all operations ---> select to_char( TO_DATE('2-AUG-2016', 'DD-MON-RR') + rownum ,'format_mask') as EXTRACT_DATES .....